# Openpyxl finds a "Nonetype" when there should not be one

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl trying to complete a small task in an Excel file. This is my code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('Test_Answer.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
n = 3
for i in range(3, sheet.max_column):
    n = n + 1
    a = sheet.cell(4, i)
    b = sheet.cell(4, n)
    av = a.value
    bv = b.value
    c = sheet.cell(9, i)
    pro = bv - av
    c.value = pro

for i in range(3, sheet.max_column):
    n = n + 1
    a = sheet.cell(5, i)
    b = sheet.cell(5, n)
    av = a.value
    bv = b.value
    c = sheet.cell(10, i)
    pro = bv - av
    c.value = pro

for i in range(3, sheet.max_column):
    n = n + 1
    a = sheet.cell(6, i)
    b = sheet.cell(6, n)
    av = a.value
    bv = b.value
    c = sheet.cell(11, i)
    pro = bv - av
    c.value = pro

for i in range(3, sheet.max_column):
    n = n + 1
    a = sheet.cell(7, i)
    b = sheet.cell(7, n)
    av = a.value
    bv = b.value
    c = sheet.cell(12, i)
    pro = bv - av
    c.value = pro

wb.save('Test_Answer2.xlsx')
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/ExcelCalculator/Excel/Test.py", line 23, in <module>
    pro = bv - av
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There should not be an issue. As you can see by the limit, I did not do "+1" at the end, meaning the last column would not be used. This is because my other variable "n" is one unit ahead with no range restriction excepting "i's", so it DOES go to the last column. This was because I planned to later do something of division, and I used ones at the last column to avoid a Nonetype error. Strangely though, the issue is appearing regardless.

Note that because this happens on the second loop, the first loop IS completed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had assumed that "n" would return back to 3 after being put into another for loop. I was wrong. By setting "n" back to 3 right before each new for loop, I fixed the issue.